# Places Autocomplete Only Return Residential Street Addresses In The US

Tags: google-places-api

we are attempting to use the new google places api text search to return suggested address completion results as a user types within an input field.

For example, user types In `545 Smi...` and `454 Smith Street, Somewhere, Some City, State...` appears as an option to select.

Currently we are making a `POST` request to `https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText?fields=places.id,places.formattedAddress` with  `testQuery` and `regionCode` body keys.

However we are noticing the results returned are very few (and borderline unusable).

Is there a better service to use to accomplish something like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the queries are partial inputs like `545 Smi` or even `454 Smith Street` you should use instead [Autocomplete (New)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-autocomplete) and send requests to https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:autocomplete

The [Text Search (New)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search) API at https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText is not designed for such queries.